# Outdoor Fan on GFCI Switch

Tags: switch, gfci, outdoor

I just replaced an outdoor ceiling fan/light on a gfci circuit, and once we completed the work and re-energized the circuit, my light switch will not move so I can test or turn on the fan. The GFCI breaker in the panelboard operates just fine when I test it. Is there something wired incorrectly or is my switch damaged for some reason?

Comment: Did any breakers trip?  how about the GFCI?  You might have wired something wrong and shorted out the switch and welded the contacts.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment "my light switch will not move" - are you talking about a wall switch that supplies power to the fan/light combo, or are you talking about the light switch on the fan itself (I'm thinking of typical cieling fan/light combo units, with separate pull chains to activate either fan or light, or both; and if a wall switch is involved, the wall switch would need to be in the on position in order to test the operation of the fan/light combo). On the other hand, if all you did was replace an existing fan, you wouldn't have need to mess with a wall switch, so it's a mystery

Comment: JACK, I upvoted your comment.   It's probably what happened.